# how to pick dates from the datepicker and insert into the model in mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

EmployeeViewModel

```
using ASP.NETMVC.Models;

namespace ASP.NETMVC.ViewModel
{
    public class EmployeeViewModel
    {
        //public Employee Employees { get; set; }
        //public EmployeeLeaves EmployeeLeaves { get; set; } 
        //public AppliedLeaves AppliedLeaves { get; set; }
        public EmployeeLeaveHeader employeeLeaveHeader { get; set; } = new();
        public List<EmployeeLeaveDetail> employeeLeaveDetail { get; set; } = new();

    }
    public class EmployeeLeaveHeader
    {
        public string firstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int TotalLeaves { get; set; }
        public int RemainingLeaves { get; set; }
        public int TotalAppliedLeaves { get; set; }

    }
    public class EmployeeLeaveDetail
    {
        public int ApplyId { get; set; }
       
        public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
        public int NoOfLeave { get; set; }
        public DateTime? AppliedOn { get; set; }

    }

}
```

EmployeeView Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ASP.NETMVC.ViewModel;
using ASP.NETMVC.Data;
using ASP.NETMVC.Models;

namespace ASP.NETMVC.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeView : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        public EmployeeView(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IActionResult Index(int EmployeeId)
        {

            List<Employee> employeeList = _db.Employees.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == EmployeeId).ToList();
            List<EmployeeLeaves> employeeLeaves = _db.EmployeeLeaves.Where(x => x.EmployeeId == EmployeeId).ToList();
            List<AppliedLeaves> appliedLeaves = _db.AppliedEmpLeaves.Where(x => x.EmployeeLeaveId == employeeLeaves.FirstOrDefault().EmployeeLeaveId).ToList();

            var employeeLeaveHeader = from emp in employeeList
                                      join empLeav in employeeLeaves
                                      on emp.EmployeeId equals empLeav.EmployeeId
                                      select new EmployeeLeaveHeader
                                      {
                                          firstName = emp.FirstName,
                                          LastName = emp.LastName,
                                          RemainingLeaves = empLeav.NoOfLeavesRemaining,
                                          TotalLeaves = empLeav.TotalNoOfLeaves,
                                          TotalAppliedLeaves = empLeav.NoOfLeavesTaken
                                      };
            var employeeLeaveDetail = appliedLeaves.Select(x => new EmployeeLeaveDetail()
            {
                ApplyId = x.ApplyId,
                AppliedOn = x.CreatedOn,
                FromDate = x.FromDate,
                ToDate = x.ToDate,
                NoOfLeave = x.NoOfLeaves
            }).ToList();

            var Data = new EmployeeViewModel();
            Data.employeeLeaveHeader = employeeLeaveHeader.FirstOrDefault();
            Data.employeeLeaveDetail = employeeLeaveDetail;
            return View(Data);
        }

        //   [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Save(int id)
        {
            List<Employee> emps = _db.Employees.ToList();
            // var obj=_db.EmployeeLeaves.Find(id);
            var EmployeeLeaveData = _db.EmployeeLeaves.SingleOrDefault(c => c.EmployeeId == id);
            //  var AppliedData = new AppliedLeaves();
            //   var fromDate = ApplyLev.FromDate;      
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "EmployeeView");
        }
    }
}
```

EmployeeView.cshtml

```
<link href="~/js~/js/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@model ASP.NETMVC.ViewModel.EmployeeViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1 style="color:black"> Employee Leave Data</h1>


<div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="border-block-color:black">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.employeeLeaveHeader.firstName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.employeeLeaveHeader.LastName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.employeeLeaveHeader.TotalLeaves)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.employeeLeaveHeader.TotalAppliedLeaves)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.employeeLeaveHeader.RemainingLeaves)
            </th>
        </tr>



        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.employeeLeaveHeader.firstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.employeeLeaveHeader.LastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.employeeLeaveHeader.TotalLeaves)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.employeeLeaveHeader.TotalAppliedLeaves)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>modelItem.employeeLeaveHeader.RemainingLeaves)

            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>
</div>





<div>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="border-block-color:black">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.employeeLeaveDetail.FirstOrDefault().ApplyId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.employeeLeaveDetail.FirstOrDefault().AppliedOn)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.employeeLeaveDetail.FirstOrDefault().FromDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.employeeLeaveDetail.FirstOrDefault().ToDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.employeeLeaveDetail.FirstOrDefault().NoOfLeave)
            </th>
        </tr>

        @if (Model.employeeLeaveDetail.Count > 0)
        {
            @foreach (var item in Model.employeeLeaveDetail)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.ApplyId)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.AppliedOn)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.FromDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ToDate)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NoOfLeave)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h3> No Entry Available</h3>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>


<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="form-group"> 
            @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.employeeLeaveDetail.FirstOrDefault().FromDate, new {style="color:black"})
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.employeeLeaveDetail.FirstOrDefault().FromDate, new {@type="date"})
            @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.employeeLeaveDetail.FirstOrDefault().ToDate, new {style="color:black"})
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.employeeLeaveDetail.FirstOrDefault().ToDate, new {@type="date"})
            <br />
            @Html.ActionLink("Save", "Save", new {id= Model.employeeLeaveDetail} , new {@class="btn btn-primary"})
        </div>
    }
</div>




@section scripts{
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function (){
     $(".datepicker").datepicker({;
     dateFormat:"dd-mm-yy",
      minDate: -0,
      maxDate: "+0M +4D"
    showOn:"both "
     });
    });

</script>

}
```

here in the cshtml view I want to take input for the employeeleavedetail.from date and then update the above table but it is giving NullreferenceException. Is there any way to take input for the employeeleavedetail.from and employeeleave.to field in date format?

Answer (score 0):

to insert data from the datepicker into the input and then save the value, I use Tempus domuninus for bootstrap. [Tempus Doominus](https://getdatepicker.com/5-4/Usage/)

I have configured in JS

```
$('.DatePicker').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'cs',
    format: 'L',
});
```

And then in cshtml I use this.

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="input-group date DatePicker" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreateDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control DatePicker" } })
                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreateDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Maybe in your case, just insert @class="datepicker" and it will work

```
<div class="form-group"> 
    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.employeeLeaveDetail.FirstOrDefault().FromDate, new {style="color:black", @class="datepicker"})
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.employeeLeaveDetail.FirstOrDefault().FromDate, new {@type="date", @class = "datepicker" })
    @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.employeeLeaveDetail.FirstOrDefault().ToDate, new {style="color:black", @class = "datepicker" })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.employeeLeaveDetail.FirstOrDefault().ToDate, new {@type="date", @class = "datepicker" })
    <br />
    @Html.ActionLink("Save", "Save", new {id= Model.employeeLeaveDetail} , new {@class="btn btn-primary"})
</div>
```